# Why cleaning in Eclipse can cause error messages?

Tags: java, eclipse, build

I cleaned my project in Eclipse and because of that, I think, I started to get the following error message:

```
at check.GameWindow$12.run(MyWindow.java:1253)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

So, I would like to ask why cleaning can cause error messages? I mean, the code before and after the cleaning is the same. Why it works differently before and after the cleaning.

Comment: Are you cleaning your project while the application is running in Eclipse?

Comment: @romaintaz, I cleaning my project in Eclipse, and then run it in Eclipse.

Comment: Do you have the automatic build activated? (Project > tick "build automatically"). Cleaning will remove the compiled classes ... and though unlikely, something might not have been rebuilt when you launched the application.

Comment: @Kellindil, yes I have the automatic build activated. So, how can I resolve the problem? How can I return the compiled classes that have been removed?

Comment: if you have the automatic build on, your classes have been recompiled. Other than you modifying the code, I can't think of anything that could have provoked a bug here. Could you post the entire stack trace of your exception (not only the stack, but also the message) and the code of "MyWindow" at line 1253 ?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, something has changed in your code that you are not aware of. When you clean your project, the only thing Eclipse does is to delete .class files in your build/ directory and recompile all sources.

If you don't have compilation errors, there should be something wrong in an an anonymous inner class in `check.GameWindow`.

Please check.